# Why is the old reference still being used while using useRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

What I am trying to do is render a list of `img` elements iterating from an array, and they have a reference named `photoRef` to their container divs. Now each image has a delete option, which fires the `handleRemovePhoto` function. Inside this function, I call my function `slideAndFade` to cause a simple animation on `photoRef.current`. After 1000ms, the function dispatches an action to remove the photo from the state. With the state update, the list of photos get re-rendered.

Now the problem I can't seem to figure out is why the `photoRef` still carries the same transform & opacity style to it, which I applied to the div referenced by photoRef, which is now deleted, and isn't being rendered. Isn't the old reference supposed to die with the element itself? But it seems like that is not the case. So can somebody explain why this is happening?

**My image component**

```js
//the animation causing function
function slideAndFade(photo) {
  photo.style.transition = "transfrom 2s ease, opacity 2s ease";
  photo.style.transform = "translateX(20px)";
  photo.style.opacity = "0";
}

//image component
export default function Image(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const photoRef = useRef();
  const handleRemovePhoto = () => {
    slideAndFade(photoRef.current);
    setTimeout(() => dispatch(removePhoto(props.index)), 1000);
  };

  return (
    <>
        <div ref={photoRef} className={classes.previewContainer}>
          <img
            src={props.src}
          />
          <button onClick={handleRemovePhoto}>Delete</button>
        </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Edit**
I've tried avoiding the use of `useRef` as that seemed to be the cause of the problem. So tried doing following instead:

```
export default function Image(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const deletedStyle = {
      transform: "translateX(20px)",
      opacity: 0,
  };
  const [isDeleted, setIsDeleted] = useState(false);
  const handleRemovePhoto = () => {
    setIsDeleted(true);
    setTimeout(() => dispatch(removePhoto(props.index)), 1000);
  };

  return (
    <>
        <div ref={photoRef} className={classes.previewContainer}>
          <img
            src={props.src}
            style={isDeleted? isDeletedStyle : {}}
          />
          <button onClick={handleRemovePhoto}>Delete</button>
        </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Still didn't work. It's still the same. I'm starting to think changing the style isn't the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what "didn't work", "still the same" means? The original problem was described in terms of useRef(), so it's a little unclear what's not working when you remove useRef(). What do you expect to see, and what do you see instead?

Comment: Is the problem that photos still have the deleted styling? It doesn't look like you ever set `isDeleted` back to `false`

Comment: yes, the problem is exactly that. I will try setting `isDeleted` to false, but assuming it works, why would it work. I'm removing the whole component from rendering, but it seems like the new component has the same styles which I set in the deleted one.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't the old reference supposed to die with the element itself?

No, React reuses elements as part of [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html). That works fine as long as React knows every way you've configured element, but does not work if you modify the inline style of an element yourself without letting React know, as you've done here.

The right way to configure inline styles with React is to set the `style` attribute in JSX: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

```js
  return (
    <>
        <div ref={photoRef} className={classes.previewContainer}>
          <img
            src={props.src}
            style={{
              transition: "transfrom 2s ease, opacity 2s ease",
              transform: "translateX(20px)",
              opacity: 0,
            }}
          />
          <button onClick={handleRemovePhoto}>Delete</button>
        </div>
    </>
  );
```

As that FAQ entry discusses, it's be even better to use CSS classes where possible.

Comment: Hey, it didn't work. Look at the edit I have made in the post.